# Recorrer y Sumar con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Como podría sumar los valores que tengo al recorrer unos productos?

Así muestro consola la cantidad de productos que se agregaron al carrito, pero ahora quiero sumar todos los productos en general.

```
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
    cnt = item.quantity;                      
    console.log(cnt);                                                                         
});
```

funcion completa

```
vtexjs.checkout.getOrderForm().done(function(orderForm) {
 //console.log(orderForm);
  items = orderForm.items;
  console.log(items);
                  
  $.each(items, function(i, item) {
       cnt = item.quantity;                      
       console.log(cnt);                                                                           
  );  
}
```

asi llega la info por consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde esta el 2 y el 1, es lo que quiero sumar, para si supera la cantidad de 3, quitar 1 del carro.

Comment: Ayudarçia mucho nos dieras un **ejemplo** de esa estructura de datos que recibes

Comment: ya edite la pregunta :)